# Combining multiple queries & returns

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.csv` file with a list of 100 `product_ids`. I have a SQL Server table which (amongst others) has a `product_id` column (4000+ ids) and a `product_description` column.

What I want to do is take the `.CSV` list of `product_ids` and run a query on the table to return a list of the relevant `product_description`.

So my simple query would be

```
select product_description 
from tablename 
where product-id = xxxxxxx.
```

But how do I supply the `xxxxxx` as a list (perhaps I just seperate with commas?) and dump the output into another csv.

Comment: So, you want to put the list of id's from your CSV into a query?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You can save your time with ms-office or even with openoffice itself. 
Short cut filter key (Alt+D+F+F).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just copy + paste the id's from the CSV into a query?

```
SELECT
    product_id
    , product_description
FROM <table>
WHERE product_id in (<<list of values from CSV>>).
```

Since they're already in a CSV, they should be comma delimited, so you can easily plug them into your query (if you open your file with a **text editor**).

Alternatively, you could do everything from SQL, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    ID integer
    , col2 ..
    , col3 ..
    etc. )
GO

BULK INSERT #TempTable
    FROM 'C:\..\file.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,           -- in case the first row contains headers (otherwise just remove this line)
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  -- default CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

And then just run:

```
SELECT
    product_id
    , product_description
FROM <table>
WHERE product_id in (SELECT ID FROM #TempTable)
```

If you want to export this result to another CSV then:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(
     'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    ,'Text;Database=D:\;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'
    ,'SELECT
          product_id
        , product_description
      FROM <table>
      WHERE product_id in (SELECT ID FROM #TempTable)' )
```

Comment: Thanks Radu, I have created a temp table :create table #tmptable
(
    Product_id varchar(30),
    Product_desc varchar(100),
    Product_long_desc varchar(2000),
    )

Comment: Then Bulk insert #tmptable from 'C:\Chris\portal.txt' with (FieldTerminator='\t', RowTerminator = '\n')
go). But sql error message says Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Bulk insert #tmptable
from 'C:\Chris\portal.txt'
with (FieldTerminator=',', RowTerminator = '\n')
go  Still returns Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (Product_id).

Comment: @user2988641 Try increasing the size of the Product_id column. Or change the datatype to nvarchar, in case the data for that column also has non-numeric characters.

Comment: I have managed to create temp table which contain 3 rows. But when I run the following query it only retruns a single row. Why is this? SELECT
    product_id
    , product_desc
FROM cm_products
WHERE product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM #tmptable2)